# Compilation of QGIS master branch under CentOS 6.3

Tags: qgis, centos

I tried to compile QGIS master branch 1.9 (qgis-Quantum-GIS-b99ff61) under CentOS for many hours now as explained [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/37180/9502) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44905/how-to-correctly-install-qgis-with-plugins-and-grass-integration-from-source) / [here](http://www.surfaces.co.il/?p=1260)

Compilation:

```
[  7%] Generating ui_qgsmapserverexportbase.py
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/PyQt4/uic/pyuic.py", line 2
exec /usr/bin/python /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/PyQt4/uic/pyuic.py ${1+"$@"}
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
make[2]: *** [python/plugins/mapserver_export/ui_qgsmapserverexportbase.py] Error 1
make[1]: *** [python/plugins/mapserver_export/CMakeFiles/mapserver_export-.-stageinstall.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[  7%] Built target sextante-._otb_description-stageinstall
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Against:

- PyQt 4.10
- Qt 4.6.2-26
- Scintilla 3.3
- Sip 4.14.5
- QScintilla 2.7.1 (closest to Python 2.6.6 on CentOS)

I am without any idea how to solve this compilation. PyQt is working and can be imported.

Comment: `pyuic.py` is part of pyqt-devel package. It is there right?

Comment: I compiled PyQt from source. pyuic.py is also located where the exec command points to.

Comment: I'm not getting the error with a yum installed PyQt4 version 4.6.2.  Can you find out what arguments are being passed in '${1+"$@"}' and run 'pyuic' from the command line?