# Install plugins for qgis in centos

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, api, c++, centos

I followed the instructions here:

[How to install QGIS on Centos 6?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37111/how-to-install-qgis-on-centos-6)

If I run:

```
QgsVectorLayer * vpoly = new QgsVectorLayer("Polygon", "pointbuffer", "memory");
QgsVectorDataProvider * provider = vpoly->dataProvider();
```

Then provider is a NULL pointer

Also, if I do:

```
QString myPluginsDir = "/usr/lib64/qgis";
QgsProviderRegistry * preg = QgsProviderRegistry::instance(myPluginsDir);
QString pluglist=preg->pluginList();
printf("plugins: %s\n",pluglist.toStdString().c_str());
```

Then it prints:

```
plugins: No data provider plugins are available. No vector layers can be loaded
```

Also, when I try to load a QgsVectorLayer with the following:

```
QgsVectorLayer * mypLayer = new QgsVectorLayer(myLayerPath, myLayerBaseName, myProviderName);
if (mypLayer->isValid()){
    qDebug("Layer is valid");
  } else {
    qDebug("Layer is NOT valid");
    return;
  }
```

Then it says that the layer is NOT valid.

This all works just fine in Ubuntu, but I can't get it to work in centos.  I think maybe it's missing all the plugins.  What am I missing?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem.

It was unrelated to the code I posted. Hopefully this will be helpful to others that get a similar error.

My code was templated from the QGIS_-Code-Examples (2_basic_main_window)

I didn't change the myPluginsDir variable. Be sure that you change it because by default it will be wrong.